# How to replace new search results with same submit button using AJAX vanilla javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, dom

I am completely stuck on how to do this. So far I am able to submit and make my searches appear, however when I make a new search it just adds on to the old search. I want to be able remove the old searches when the submit button is clicked on and replace it with my new search.

I have tried several ways but when I click on the submit button it ends up with no searches appearing.

If it helps, I am getting my data from an API.

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

So far, I have added an eventListener to my button, which when clicked on makes a XMLHttpRequest(). Then it runs a for loop to extract my data.

Comment: It'd be useful to see the actual code, but basically you need to clear the DOM node that contains your search results, before adding new ones.

Comment: Please edit your question and add your HTML and JS code (or upload to jsbin.com, etc. and provide link)

Comment: Wherever you are placing these results after you get them from your API, you need to clear that space before you add the new ones. This is just DOM manipulation, not really anything to do with ajax or APIs. Search for the JS syntax to clear an element's contents.